# Fourier transform, Dirac delta and bivariate function

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let us define the Fourier transform in the signal processing convention:

\begin{align}
S(f)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}s(t)e^{-i2\pi f t}dt \\
s(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}S(f)e^{i2\pi f t}df \quad .
\end{align}

First, let $s=\delta_0$ be the Dirac delta's distribution. It is the inverse Fourier transform of $S(f)=1$:
\begin{align}
\delta(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i2\pi f t}df \quad .
\end{align}

Then, consider a bivariate function $S(t,f)$ so that its inverse Fourier transform with respect to $f$ is the Dirac delta:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}S(t,f)e^{i2\pi f t}df&=\delta(t) \quad .
\end{align}

**My question:**

### **Is it true that $S(t,f)=1$?**

Comment: Of course no. $S(t,f)=1$ iff for every $u$, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}S(u,f)e^{i2\pi f t}df=\delta(t)$. And those are Fourier transforms in the sense of distribution, not true integrals.

Comment: Ok, this is what I suspected. Do you have any idea of a counterexample?